# Iterating over a list of URLs in an HTML template using Python/Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

This seems like a very basic problem but I can't figure it out. I'm passing a list of URLs into an HTML page and trying to print each one out in an href tag. I'm using Flask to run the test server, and can confirm that the variables are being passed in correctly (I can print out the entire list or elements from it).

My app route:

```
import doaudit # separate Py script that gets these urls

@app.route('/audit', methods = ['GET'])
def audit():
    return render_template('audit.html', listOfUrls = doaudit.listOfUrls)
```

My template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Data Audit</title>   
</head>
<body>

        {% for url in listOfUrls %}        
        <script language="JavaScript">
            document.write( "<a href=\"" + url + "\">linktext</a>" );
        </script>
        {% endfor %}

    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried variations on:

```
document.write( "<a href=\"" + '{{ listOfUrls[i] }}' + "\">linktext</a>" );
```

and iterating over all the i's but that doesn't work either.

The length of the list can vary, so I need an iterative solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
{% for url in listOfUrls %}        
    <script language="JavaScript">
        document.write( "<a href=\"" + {{ url|tojson|safe }} + "\">linktext</a>" );
    </script>
{% endfor %}
```

The `{{ url }}` part tells Jinja2 (the template engine) that this `url` is actually the variable that you called so in the `for url in blabla`. Without it, it's printed as is. You can see it when viewing the source in your browser. This means it will be interpreted as a JS variable, which will be `undefined`, equivalent to an empty string, which you then see.

**EDIT:** added the `tojson|safe` calls, to make sure it will not break the JS code. You could do it this way : `<a href=\"{{ url }}\">linktext</a>`. But then a `"` would break your html/js code.

**EDIT 2:** what the `tojson` filter does, is make it suitable to be put inside JS code. and the `safe` filter tells the rendering engine that it should not treat it as any text (which should be escaped to show properly in HTML), but treat it as safe text (HTML or not).

Comment: Nailed it. Doesn't work at all without tojson|safe for my application. Thanks.

Comment: @acpigeon Great. I updated my answer to give a bit more details about the filters used, thought it might be a bit more useful with these.